# randomize featureCollection

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, random

I have a geojson feature collection with features like below in the entire collection.

```
{ geometry: { coordinates: [Array], type: 'LineString' },
properties: { angle: 120.2},
type: 'Feature' }
```

Is there a way which I can randomise the features in the collection and make them not sequential in javascript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: Is this an array, containing many of these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `Array#sort` combined with `Math.random`.

```js
const features = [{
  geometry: {
    coordinates: [Array],
    type: 'LineString'
  },
  properties: {
    angle: 120.2
  },
  type: 'Feature'
}, {
  geometry: {
    coordinates: [Array],
    type: 'LineString'
  },
  properties: {
    angle: 100.2
  },
  type: 'Feature'
}, {
  geometry: {
    coordinates: [Array],
    type: 'LineString'
  },
  properties: {
    angle: 4.2
  },
  type: 'Feature'
}, {
  geometry: {
    coordinates: [Array],
    type: 'LineString'
  },
  properties: {
    angle: 15.2
  },
  type: 'Feature'
}]

const randomSort = (arr) => {
  return arr.sort(() => {
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
  })
}

console.log(randomSort(features))
```

Comment: I dont want to pick the random feature. But  want to randomly sort the features in the collection.